# AngularJS, AngularUi (Bootstrap) and NgRoute

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ngroute

Im using AngularJS 1.4.1, ngRoute 1.4.1 and https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

The base structure is

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <base href="/">
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I use ngRoute to load each page of my website such as about, contact us, etc... into the div with ng view.

When the page is loaded into ng view using

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngProgress', 'ui.bootstrap']); 

myApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){$routeProvider
.when('/about',{templateUrl:'about.php',controller:'mainController'})
.otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
                                                        
staffPanelApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, $templateCache, ngProgress) {
  $templateCache.removeAll();
  ngProgress.start();
  $scope.$route = $route;
  $scope.$location = $location;
  $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
  ngProgress.complete();
});
```

the ui bootstrap feature such as alert should work but it doesn't appear to work in the ngview, it only seems to work when i add it to the main base page. Is there a way to get it to work in the ngView loaded page?

Example Bootstrap UI Feature:

```html
<alert type="success">This should work</alert>
```

**Update:**
Plunker but couldn't get ngroute to work but the basis is there:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Njg16e01Ocv1iC1qzn7A?p=preview

Comment: Can you post a plunker/jsfiddle? try ui-view?

Comment: I created a plunker but i couldn't get ngRoute to work on the link but the basis is there http://plnkr.co/edit/Njg16e01Ocv1iC1qzn7A?p=preview

Comment: What's up Bob, did my answer help you?

Comment: after modifying your example to work with plunker by removing HTML5Mode and `$templateCache.removeAll();`, The feature in question seemed to work normally.  Perhaps you are breaking the feature by removing the Template Cache?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you create controller on 'staffPanelApp' but your ngApp is called myApp?